# Quartz Scheduler did not pick the scheduler mentioned in the quartz.properties

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, weblogic8.x

In my web application the scheduler is not picked up during the startup of my weblogic 8.1 server. It took the '`DefaultQuartzScheduler'insted` of my Scheduler in my `quartz.properties`.

The same code and setup is working fine in my local environment.

Kindly help me what is causing the scheduler to start?

Thanks in advance..!

**Extra log compared with my local environment:**
2012-11-01 04:31:23,257 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool -Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System

**Logs:**

```
2012-11-01 04:31:23,180 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources -Initializing, config='ftp', returnNull=true
2012-11-01 04:31:23,245 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet -Factory initialized from file '/WEB-INF/tileDefinitions.xml'.
2012-11-01 04:31:23,245 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin -Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''.
2012-11-01 04:31:23,257 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool -Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'
2012-11-01 04:31:23,260 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore -RAMJobStore initialized.
2012-11-01 04:31:23,261 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory -Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
2012-11-01 04:31:23,261 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory -Quartz scheduler version: 1.4.5
2012-11-01 04:31:23,261 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler -Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started
2012-11-01 04:31:23,263 [ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.System'] INFO  EMD -DefaultQuartzScheduler Scheduler  Successfully Started
```

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this issue? I am facing very similar case like yours.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it looks like Quartz is simply not finding your quartz.properties file ("initialized from default resource file..."). The two most likely causes are:

1. The quartz.properties file is simply absent from the WAR
2. The quartz.properties file is in the wrong place (it should be in WEB-INF/classes)

Comment: quartz.propeties file is present in the WEB-INF/classes.